# Custom conversion to Dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is coming from an api, the string version looks like this:

```
0

2023-04-17 4.82

2023-04-18 4.82

2023-04-19 4.82

2023-04-20 4.82

2023-04-21 4.81
```

when I call df.to_json(orient = 'records') it looks like this (no good at all):

```
[{"0":4.82},{"0":4.82},{"0":4.82},{"0":4.82},{"0":4.81}]
```

What I'd really like is for it to look like this:

```
[{Date:"2023-04-17", "Rate":4.82},{Date:"2023-04-18", "Rate":4.82},{Date:"2023-04-19", "Rate":4.82},{Date:"2023-04-20", "Rate":4.82},{Date:"2023-04-21", "Rate":4.81}]
```

There could potentially be many rows of data so I need the conversion to perform well

Comment: try `df= df.reset_index()` , then rename your cols `df.columns = ['date', 'rate']` and then do `df.to_json(...)`

Comment: Thanks very much that worked (almost) - I got the following:[{"date":1681689600000,"rate":4.82},{"date":1681776000000,"rate":4.82},{"date":1681862400000,"rate":4.82},{"date":1681948800000,"rate":4.82},{"date":1682035200000,"rate":4.81}]

Comment: that's because datetime objects are not serializable. Convert them to strings first. After setting the columns, do `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` and _then_ do `df.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by first converting the dataframe to a list of dictionaries and then using the json module to convert it to JSON format with the desired structure.

Here's an example code snippet that should work:

```
import json

# assuming your dataframe is named `df`
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')

# iterate over the records and format the date and rate values
formatted_data = []
for record in data:
    formatted_data.append({"Date": record["0"].split()[0], "Rate": float(record["0"].split()[1])})

# convert the formatted data to JSON
json_data = json.dumps(formatted_data)

# print the resulting JSON string
print(json_data)
```

This code first converts the dataframe to a list of dictionaries using the to_dict method with the orient parameter set to 'records'. It then iterates over each record in the list and formats the date and rate values as required by creating a new dictionary with "Date" and "Rate" keys. Finally, it uses the json.dumps method to convert the formatted data to a JSON string.

This approach should perform well even with large dataframes since it avoids using slow loops and leverages the built-in json module for efficient serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion while parsing the API response. This allows you to take advantage of any vectorization which `pandas` provides, particularly if you end up doing some more interesting things with the data.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
data = '''0

2023-04-17 4.82

2023-04-18 4.82

2023-04-19 4.82

2023-04-20 4.82

2023-04-21 4.81'''
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(data),
    sep=' ',
    names=['Date', 'Rate'],
    dtype={'Date': str, 'Rate': float},
    skiprows=[0]
)
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

```json
'[{"Date":"2023-04-17","Rate":4.82},{"Date":"2023-04-18","Rate":4.82},{"Date":"2023-04-19","Rate":4.82},{"Date":"2023-04-20","Rate":4.82},{"Date":"2023-04-21","Rate":4.81}]'
```

Explanation of arguments to `pd.read_csv()`:

1. `io.StringIO(data)`: data from API response, should be obvious
2. `sep=' '`: separator between cells, should be obvious
3. `names=['Date', 'Rate']`: column headers
4. `dtype={'Date': str, 'Rate': float}`: types to cast each column's values to
5. `skiprows=[0]`: which rows to omit, this omits the first row since it's just a `0` and we don't want it in the result

Empty rows are skipped by default.